# Vue.js not recognizing data keys

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Following the official guide, I am trying to build a simple form that outputs its input into a div on the same template.

Here is my code

```
<template lang="html">
  <div>
    <input type="text" name="firstname" value="" v-model="firstname">
    <input type="submit">

    <div>
      <h1>First name</h1>
      <p>{{ firstname }}</p>
    </div>

  </div>
</template>

<script>
  export default {
    data: function() {
      'firstname': '',
    }
  }
</script>

<style>
</style>
```

And here is the error:

```
SyntaxError: Unexpected token, expected ; (28:15)

  26 | export default {
  27 |   data: function() {
> 28 |     'firstname': '',
     |                ^    


 @ ./src/App.vue 8:18-97
```

I have tried to

- remove the quotes from the data keys
- change the data function to an object

Frankly out of ideas as this is so close to the documentation.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[data](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#data-Must-Be-a-Function) must be a function which must return the object of defined data variables, like following:

```
  data: function () {
    return {
      'firstname': '',
    }
  }
```

Comment: Yeah that was overlooked

Answer (score 2):

You have a syntax error as you're not actually returning an object in the function:

```
data: function() {
  return {
    firstname: '',
  }
}
```